# Google-Cloud Speech API and Heroku events.js error

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to get a simple Google Cloud/Speech app running to convert my Mic audio to text. My index.js.below

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const record = require('node-record-lpcm16');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
 const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
 const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
 const languageCode = 'en-US';

const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode,
  },
  interimResults: false, // If you want interim results, set this to true
};

// Create a recognize stream
const recognizeStream = client
  .streamingRecognize(request)
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', data =>
    process.stdout.write(
      data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
        ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
        : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
    )
  );

// Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
record
  .start({
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    threshold: 0,
    // Other options, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#options
    verbose: false,
    recordProgram: 'rec', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
    silence: '10.0',
  })
  .on('error', console.error)
  .pipe(recognizeStream);

console.log('Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.');



app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

If I run the above code locally, it works perfectly. If I remove all the Google Speech code, the server runs fine. But when using the above ([Same as the Docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize)) Heroku spins up then throws an error.

```
2019-02-25T09:07:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-02-25T09:07:39.926417+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-02-25T09:07:39.926435+00:00 app[web.1]: > socket-chat-example@0.0.1 start /app
2019-02-25T09:07:39.926437+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2019-02-25T09:07:39.926439+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-02-25T09:07:40.617413+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626395+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:174
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626399+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626401+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626403+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626405+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: spawn rec ENOENT
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626407+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626410+00:00 app[web.1]:     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626412+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626414+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626416+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626417+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626419+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event at:
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626421+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626423+00:00 app[web.1]:     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626425+00:00 app[web.1]:     [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
2019-02-25T09:07:40.626427+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
2019-02-25T09:07:40.636937+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I have all the Google Cloud credentials set up as environment variables in Heroku and they seem to be working fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is the first result from Google: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/275